# Explicit keyword applied to operator instead of constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-keyword, explicit

In the class below,

Why would you make the operators `explicit`. I thought that `explicit` was to prevent implicit calling of constructors?

```
 class Content
            {
public:

 virtual ~Content() = 0;
 virtual explicit operator float&();
 virtual explicit operator long long&();
 virtual explicit operator std::string&()
}
```

Comment: `explicit` prevents implicit conversions. User defined conversion operators can also allow implicit conversions unless made `explicit`.

Comment: "_I thought that explicit was to prevent implicit calling of constructors?_" Why do you think, it is meant for constructors only? Who told you that?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Anyone who uses a C++03 compiler, or older ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that explicit was to prevent implicit calling of
>   constructors?

Since C++11 it also applies to [*user-defined conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) (a.k.a. the *cast operator*).

> Why would you make the operators `explicit`

Used in this context, the `explicit` keyword makes the conversion eligible only for *direct-initialization* and *explicit conversions*. See here under [[class.conv.fct¶2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv#fct-2):

> A conversion function may be explicit ([dcl.fct.spec]), in which case
>   **it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for
>   direct-initialization** ([dcl.init]). Otherwise, user-defined
>   conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and
>   initializations.

This aids you in making sure the compiler doesn't try the conversion against your intention, so that you have to explicitly cast it yourself, leaving less room for error. Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    explicit operator int() {return 0;}
    operator int*() {return nullptr;}
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    //int xi = foo; // Error, conversion must be explicit
    int i = static_cast<int>(foo); // OK, conversion is explicit
    int* i_ptr = foo; // OK, implicit conversion to `int*` is allowed

    int i_direct(foo); // OK, direct initialization allowed
    int* i_ptr_direct(foo); // OK, direct initialization after implicit conversion

    return 0;
}
```

It can also help resolve ambiguity in cases where multiple conversion options apply, leaving the compiler without a criteria for deciding which one to choose:

```
struct Bar
{
    operator int() {return 1;}
    operator char() {return '1';}
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;    
    //double d = bar; // Error, implicit conversion is ambiguous    
    return 0;
}
```

Add `explicit`:

```
struct Bar
{
    operator int() {return 1;}
    explicit operator char() {return '1';}
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;    
    double d = bar; // OK, implicit conversion to `int` is the only option    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, as a general rule conversions (if these are absolutely necessary) of user-defined types should be member function, for example: `int Foo::toInt()`, `bool Foo::toBool()`; then... if it is convenient for clarity/security in the client code, to define an explicit conversion operator (say, `explicit Foo::operator int()`), and only if there are very powerful reasons, an implicit conversion operator. It is much more important to be (clear, explicit, simple) than to be clever.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGustavoLópez Agreed : ) But speaking of being explicit (ha) I was trying to explicitly answer the question asked -- namely, regarding usage of the `explicit` keyword for conversions.

Comment: Mine is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGustavoLópez you're 100% OK, I was just being apologetic about why not include it in the answer in the first place : )

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
struct Content
{
    operator float() { return 42.f; }  
    friend Content operator+(Content& lhs, float) { return lhs; }
};

int main()
{
    Content c{};
    c + 0; //  error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+'
}
```

Here, the compiler cannot choose between `operator+(Content&, float)` and `operator+(float, int)`. Making the float operator `explicit` resolves this ambiguity*:

```
c + 0; // operator+(Content&, float)
```

or

```
static_cast<float>(c) + 0; // operator+(float, int)
```

---

*) provided it makes sense to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers cover how it works, but I think you should be told why it was added to C++.

A smart pointer usually has a conversion to `bool` so you can do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> foo;
if (foo) {
  *foo = 7;
}
```

where `if(foo)` converts `foo` to `bool`.  Unfortunately:

```
int x = foo+2;
```

converts `foo` to `bool`, then to `int`, then adds `2`.  This is almost always a bug.  This is permitted because while only one user defined conversion is done, a user defined conversion followed by a built in conversion can silently occur.

To fix this programmers would do crazy things like add:

```
struct secret {
  void unused();
};
struct smart_ptr {
  using secret_mem_ptr = void(secret::*)();
  operator secret_mem_ptr() const { return 0; }
};
```

and `secret_mem_ptr` is a secret pointer to member.  A pointer to member has a built in conversion to `bool`, so:

```
smart_ptr ptr;
if (!ptr) {
}
```

"works" -- `ptr` is convert to `secret_mem_ptr`, which then is convered to `bool`, which is then used to decide which branch to take.

This was more than a bit of a hack.

They added `explicit` on conversion operators to solve this exact problem.

Now:

```
struct smart_ptr {
  explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};
```

doesn't permit:

```
smart_ptr ptr;
int x = 3 + ptr;
```

but it does permit:

```
if (ptr) {
}
```

because the rules were hand-crafted to support exactly that use case.  It also doesn't permit:

```
bool test() {
  smart_ptr ptr;
  return ptr;
}
```

here, you have to type:

```
bool test() {
  smart_ptr ptr;
  return (bool)ptr;
}
```

where you explicitly convert `ptr` to `bool`.

(I am usually really against C-style casts; I make an exception in the case of `(bool)`).

Comment: "*I am usually really against C-style casts; I make an exception in the case of `(bool)`*" - why?  You should always use `static_cast` when invoking explicit conversions: `return static_cast<bool>(ptr);` If such a conversion is defined, it will be invoked, otherwise the code will fail to compile

Comment: @RemyLebeau Find me a case where `(bool)(x)` does the wrong (or dangerous) thing and `static_cast<bool>(x)` does the right thing (including fail to compile due to an error when the cast would be dangerous).  If you can, I will reconsider, but I could not.

Answer (score 1):

You would use it if you wanted a `Content` object never to be implicitly converted to (say) a `float`. This could happen in the following way:

```
 void f( float f );
 ....
 Content c;
 f( c );      // conversion from Content to float
```

Without the `explicit` qualifier, the conversion happens implicitly; with it, you get a compilation error.

Silent, implicit conversions can be the source of a lot of confusion and/or bugs, so it's generally better to make the operators explicit , or probably better yet to provide named functions, such as `ToFloat`, which tell the reader exactly what is going on.